# diagonally move of slides for splide

Tags: svelte, splidejs

How can I change the slide track direction for `splide.js` so that the slides move diagonally.I tried to use `rotate(-2deg)` in CSS, but but my slider was freezing.

```
<Splide
options={{
autoScroll: {
speed: 1,
pauseOnFocus: false,
pauseOnHover: false,
},
autoWidth: true,
pagination: false,
arrows: false,
type: "loop",
focus: "center",
drag: false,
}}
extensions={{ AutoScroll }}
>
```